# Generic Constraints And Type Parameters Mess

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have the following base abstract class defined as:

```
public abstract class BaseObject<T> : IComparable, IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T> {}
```

I also have an interface defined as:

```
public interface ICode<T> where T : struct
{
    T Code { get; }
}
```

Now I want to derive a class that is inherited from `BaseObject<T>` and includes interface `ICode<T>`.

I tried to define it like that:

```
public class DerivedObject<T, U> : BaseObject<T>, ICode<U> where T : DerivedObject<T, U> where U : struct
{

    public DerivedObject(U code)
    {
        Code = code;
    }

    // From BaseObject
    protected override int InstanceCompareTo(T obj)
    {
        return Code.CompareTo(obj.Code);
    }

    // From BaseObject
    protected override bool InstanceEquals(T obj)
    {
        return Code.Equals(obj.Code);
    }

    // From ICode
    U _Code;

    public U Code 
    { 
        get { return _Code; }
        protected set { _Code = value; }
    }
}
```

The only error that comes from the compiler is for `Code.CompareTo(obj.Code)` with the message:

*'U' does not contain a definition for 'CompareTo' and no extension method 'CompareTo' accepting a first argument of type 'U' could be found.*

But `U` is a value type and should know `CompareTo`.

Have you any idea what I am doing wrong, or if I do all wrong?

My final aim is to derive classes such these:

```
    public class Account : DerivedObject<Account, int>
    public class ItemGroup : DerivedObject<ItemGroup, string>
```

Big Thanks In Advance!

Comment: I think its because U is a struct and you didn't specify any generic conditions on him, but i'm not familiar with structs because I never found a reason to use them.

Comment: I think you are running to the same confusion I had... struct keyword as a generic type parameter means value type and not really structs. Don't ask me why they decided to use the same keyword for two different things!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary for a `struct` type to have a `CompareTo` method. You have to enforce it using constraint:

```
public class DerivedObject<T, U> : BaseObject<T>, ICode<U>
    where T : DerivedObject<T, U>
    where U : struct, IComparable<U> {}
```

`CompareTo` method is part of `IComparable<T>` contract. And it has nothing to do with `U` being a value type. That is why, you have to add a generic constraint that states `U` is `IComparable<U>`.

Comment: Well, as Tom Tom said all major structs include IComparable and IComparable<T>, but not all for the compiler to accept that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> But U is a value type and should know
>   CompareTo.

Ah - no. Jusst because U is a value type does notmean it has to have COmpareTo, and "should know" is something you say, but did not put into your class definition.

Demand that U also implements IComparable and "should know" is something the compiler can understand. CompareTo is not a propertly of struct, but because all major structs also implement IComparable.